# MUI Buttons color keeps changing when page loads

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I'm encountering an incredibly weird issue in MUI. Here's what the button looks like WHILE the page is loading:
[image]

However, when the image finishes loading, I get the following:

[image]

The button is there, it's just... White? I've tried removing my theme, no help. Hovering over the button also restores the color. Extremely weird! I'm using NextJS. I have no idea why this would happen. If I use DevTools, I realize that if I uncheck the background-color property of the "button" element it goes back to normal:

[image]

```
'use client';
import { ShoppingCart as ShoppingCartIcon } from '@mui/icons-material';
import UploadFileIcon from '@mui/icons-material/UploadFile';
import { AppBar, Button, Typography, useTheme } from '@mui/material';


const TopNavbar = () => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    return (
        <div
            id="top-nav"
            className="h-16 w-full px-8 static"
            style={{
                backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
                color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
            }}
        >
            <div className="flex items-center w-full h-full">
                <div className="mr-6">
                    <ShoppingCartIcon className="text-4xl" />
                </div>
                <div className="flex-grow">
                    <Typography variant="h6">Products</Typography>
                </div>
                <div className="flex">
                    <Button variant="contained" color="secondary">
                        <UploadFileIcon className="mr-2" /> Import
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default TopNavbar;
```